# Python exception not caught

Tags: python, exception, logging

I am currently playing with sockets and JSON in Python where I have the following code:

```
class RCHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):    
    def setup(self):
        pass

    def handle(self):
        raw = self.request.recv(1024)
        recv = raw.strip()

        if not recv:
            return

        # do some logging
        logging.debug("RECV: (%s)" % recv)

        try:
            data = json.loads(recv)
        except:
            logging.exception('JSON parse error: %s' % recv)
            return

        if recv == 'quit':
            return
```

The problem is that when I send a faulty JSON string, e.g. `'{"method": "test"'`, the exception seems to be caught, but I still get the following traceback:

```
DEBUG: 20/09/2015 12:33:57 - RECV: ({"method": "test")
ERROR: 20/09/2015 12:33:57 - JSON parse error: {"method": "test"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./remoteControl.py", line 68, in handle
    data = json.loads(recv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 17 (char 16)
```

What am I missing here? I am not supposed to get a traceback if I catch the exception right? My server class extends ThreadingTCPServer if that has anything to do with it.

When I ran another python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import socket

d = '{"method": "test"'

try:
    data = json.loads(d)
except:
    print "fail"
```

It only prints "fail" and no traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *did* catch the exception, but you are telling `logging` to include the exception information (which includes the traceback), by using the `Logger.exception` method here:

```
except:
    logging.exception('JSON parse error: %s' % recv)
```

From the [method documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.exception):

> Logs a message with level `ERROR` on the root logger. The arguments are interpreted as for `debug()`, except that any passed `exc_info` is not inspected. **Exception info is always added to the logging message**. This function should only be called from an exception handler.

*Emphasis mine*.

Also see the [`Formatter.formatException()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatException); it is this method that does the exception formatting here:

> Formats the specified exception information (a standard exception tuple as returned by `sys.exc_info()`) as a string. This default implementation just uses `traceback.print_exception()`. The resulting string is returned.

and [`traceback.print_exception()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception) does this:

> Print exception information and up to *limit* stack trace entries from *traceback* to *file*.

If you did not want the exception to be included, use `logging.error()` instead:

```
except:
    logging.error('JSON parse error: %s' % recv)
```

or provide a custom [`Formatter` subclass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) that formats the exception information without the traceback.

Comment: Ah jeez, that I did not expect. I spent hours debugging a bug that just wasn't there :P Thanks for your answer! =)